# ChoiceValidator not triggered using Api-Platform when using PATCH endpoint

Tags: symfony, validation, api-platform.com, symfony6

Cross-posted on ApiPlatform's Github, now labeled as "bug": https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/2443

---

I'm setting up a skeleton for myself that has the basics included. Part of that is a User which can have Roles. A Role is not an Entity, it exists only as strings and they're stored as part of User records as a `json` column (Postgres).

**The trouble I'm facing**: Both POST and PATCH endpoints for creating and updating a User have the same Constraints. However, the PATCH endpoint fails to validate incoming data prior to trying to use it.

The `POST /api/users` & `PATCH /api/users/:uuid` endpoint are configured like so:

```yaml
ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post:
    processor: App\User\PasswordHasher
    normalizationContext:
        groups:
            - user:item
    denormalizationContext:
        groups:
            - user:post
    validationContext:
        groups:
            - user:post
ApiPlatform\Metadata\Patch:
    processor: App\User\PasswordHasher
    normalizationContext:
        groups:
            - user:item
    denormalizationContext:
        groups:
            - user:patch
    validationContext:
        groups:
            - user:patch
```

The validation for this is configured like so:

```yaml
roles:
    - Choice:
        #  callback: [ App\Role\Role, getRoles ]     # <-- Alternative, same result
        choices: [ 'ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN' ]  
        multiple: true
        message: 'The role "{{ value }}" is not a valid role.'
        min: 0
        minMessage: 'You must select at least {{ limit }} choice(s).'
        groups:
            - user:post
            - user:patch
```

When debugging, I find that the class `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint\Choice` gets instantiated and the correct options are present:

[image: Instantiated Choice Constraint object]

However, the `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\ChoiceValidator::validate` function is never called. I have set a breakpoint on the first line in that function, but it never gets there. (*It **is** called when using the POST endpoint.*)

Instead of using the validator, it continues as if the content is valid and tries to add an invalid "Role" value (`INVALID`) to the User object. That it even attempts this means it got past the validation stage.

---

#### Observations

- The same code is being used for the `POST /api/users` endpoint, where using `INVALID` as the value fails with a `422 Unprocessable Content`, as expected
- Because the POST and PATCH endpoints have the same configuration for Resource (Entity) and the same Constraints, I expect the difference in handling to be because of the HTTP Method

  - `POST` calls the `ChoiceValidator::validate` function
  - `PATCH` **does not call** the `ChoiceValidator::validate` function

---

#### Additional code for context

Behat is the feature testing framework of choice for process and data validation. Below are the 2 tests, one for POST and the other for PATCH, that verify trying to save `INVALID` should fail.

`POST /api/users` - This one passes

```
    # Purpose: validate that an administrator cannot create a user with an invalid role
    Scenario Outline: An administrator cannot create a user with an invalid role
        Given there is no user with email "john.doe@example.com"
        And add "Accept" header equal to "<accept>"
        When a POST request is sent to "/api/users" with body:
        """
        {
            "email": "john.doe@example.com",
            "plainPassword": "SuperSecretPassword@123!",
            "roles": <roles>
        }
        """
        Then the response status code should be 422
        And the response should be in JSON
        And a user with email "john.doe@example.com" should not exist
        And the header "Content-Type" should contain "application/problem+json"
        And the header "Content-Type" should contain "charset=utf-8"
        And the JSON should be a valid item according to the schema "exception.schema.json"

        Examples:
            | accept              | roles                     |
            | application/json    | ["INVALID"]               |
            | application/ld+json | ["INVALID", "ROLE_ADMIN"] |
```

`PATCH /api/users/:uuid` - This one fails

```
    # Purpose: validate that an administrator cannot patch a user with an invalid role
    Scenario Outline: An administrator cannot patch a user with an invalid role
        Given there is no user with email "john.doe@example.com"
        And there is no user with uuid "1a2b3c4d-1a2b-1a2b-1a2b-1a2b3c4d5e6f"
        And there is a user with email "john.doe@example.com" and uuid "1a2b3c4d-1a2b-1a2b-1a2b-1a2b3c4d5e6f"
        And add "Content-Type" header equal to "application/merge-patch+json"
        When a PATCH request is sent to "/api/users/1a2b3c4d-1a2b-1a2b-1a2b-1a2b3c4d5e6f" with body:
        """
        {
            "roles": <roles>
        }
        """
        Then the response status code should be 422
        And the response should be in JSON
        And the stored value for roles of user with email "john.doe@example.com" should not contain roles:
            | <roles> |
        And the header "Content-Type" should contain "application/problem+json"
        And the header "Content-Type" should contain "charset=utf-8"
        And the JSON should be a valid item according to the schema "exception.schema.json"

        Examples:
            | roles                          |
            | ["INVALID"]                    |
            | ["INVALID", "ANOTHER_INVALID"] |
```

Output of failed step:

```
    Examples:
      | roles       |
      | ["INVALID"] |
        Failed step: Then the response status code should be 422
        Current response status code is 404, but 422 expected. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ExpectationException)
        │
        │  JSON body:
        │  {
        │      "type": "https:\/\/tools.ietf.org\/html\/rfc2616#section-10",
        │      "title": "An error occurred",
        │      "detail": "The role 'INVALID' does not exist.",
        │      "trace": [
        │          // THE STACK TRACE HERE
```

The output `detail` message comes from `Role::addRole` which checks if the provided Role string value `INVALID` exists in the array of known roles (`['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN']`).